# how to render or create new elements in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, render, react-dom

so i am trying to make a program where i can make or create new elements in react js on a click i tried few things but it gives me few errors

```
import React from 'react'
import { ReactDOM } from 'react'
export default class Create extends React.Component{
    render(){
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello</h1>,document.getElementById('box'))
        return(
            <>
            <div id='box'></div>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

this is what i tried to do where i tried to add a new HEADING element in box element but it gives me a few error
i am new to react so i am sorry for some rookie mistakes

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this guide how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Start by reading the [docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn).

Comment: Please, be specific with the errors you're having when using stackoverflow, so that we all save time. What is your React version? I suggest using Code Sandbox to reproduce accurately your situation. Also, please read the docs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of way of achieving this behaviour.

One way is to keep track of an Integer, for which you will render an Element (header). Pressing a button will then increase the number, so a new one is rendered.

The same idea can be achieved using arrays, objects etc...

---

Example using an simple Integer:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Heading = (props) => {
    return <h3>{'Header: #' + (props.id + 1)}</h3>;
}

const Example = () => {

    const [num, setNum] = useState(1);
    
    const bumpNum = () => setNum(num + 1);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 onClick={bumpNum}>{'Press me to bump!'}</h1>
            {Array(num).fill().map((_, i) => <Heading id={i} />)}
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```